# Team City and Visual Studio 2010 and Coverage Tool

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, teamcity, code-coverage

In my team we shall use Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0 as soon as possible and I have a question regarding VS 2010 and Team City. 
In VS2010 there is a simple tool to measure mstest coverage. Question: Is it possible to read the result of ms-Coverage from team city?
If yes, how do we set up that configuration.

best Regard 
Henrik

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, I'd appreciate a "mark as answer". Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use the vsinstr.exe and vsperfmon.exe command lines tools to generate coverage data. See [Code Coverage with Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299398.aspx).

Once you have the code coverage files, you need to get TeamCity to report the data. [This article](http://pwigle.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/code-metrics-statistics-with-team-city/) should get you started, in particular, look under the "Configure TeamCity to display statistics" header.

Comment: so basically we can do the coverage with the VisualStudio Tool, and display reports with that 'configure teamcity to display statistics' part in article?  and btw, is opencover a better alternative? or the VS tool is fine by itself?

Comment: I don't know; my answer is 3 years old, YMMV.